# how can I have nginx require HTTPS for one location, while having it be optional for all others?

Tags: http, https, nginx

Currently I have nginx configured with a single site that serves both HTTP and HTTPS, using two `listen` directives:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen 443 ssl;
```

I'd like to use this configuration for all locations within the site; however there is only location where I would like to require HTTPS.

```
location / {
  // Both HTTP and HTTPS
}

location /admin {
  // Require HTTPS
}
```

How would I go about doing this?  Are seperate HTTP and HTTPS server configs required?

Answer (score 0):

I'd split those to 2 servers

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        #normal config
    }

    location /admin {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        #normal config for frontend
    }

    location /admin {
        #admin settings
    }
}
```

You can split the common config into a separate file and include them in both servers instead of rewriting both every time you change any thing